# How to deal with dataset that contains both discrete and continuous data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, classification

I was training a model that contains 8 features that allows us to predict the probability of a room been sold.

---

Region: The region the room belongs to (an integer, taking value between 1 and 10)

Date:The date of stay (an integer between 1‐365, here we consider only one‐day
request)

Weekday: Day of week (an integer between 1‐7)

Apartment: Whether the room is a whole apartment (1) or just a room (0)

#beds:The number of beds in the room (an integer between 1‐4)

Review: Average review of the seller (a continuous variable between 1 and 5)

Pic Quality: Quality of the picture of the room (a continuous variable between 0 and 1)

Price: he historic posted price of the room (a continuous variable)

Accept:Whether this post gets accepted (someone took it, 1) or not (0) in the end

---

Column Accept is the "y". Hence, this is a binary classification.

We have plot the data and some of the data were skewed so we applied power transform.
We tried a neural network, ExtraTrees, XGBoost, Gradient boost, Random forest. They all gave about 0.77 AUC. However, when we tried them on the test set, the AUC dropped to 0.55 with a precision of 27%.

I am not sure where when wrong but my thinking was that the reason may due to the mixing of discrete and continuous data. Especially some of them are either 0 or 1.
Can anyone help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

df_train = pd.read_csv('case2_training.csv')

X, y = df_train.iloc[:, 1:-1], df_train.iloc[:, -1]
y = y.astype(np.float32)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)

from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer

pt = PowerTransformer()

transform_list = ['Pic Quality', 'Review', 'Price']
X_train[transform_list] = pt.fit_transform(X_train[transform_list])
X_test[transform_list] = pt.transform(X_test[transform_list])

for i in transform_list:
    df = X_train[i]
    ax = df.plot.hist()
    ax.set_title(i)
    plt.show()
    
# Normalization
sc = MinMaxScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

X_train = X_train.astype(np.float32)
X_test = X_test.astype(np.float32)


from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

clf =  RandomForestClassifier(random_state=123, n_estimators=50)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
yhat = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

# AUC metric
train_accuracy = roc_auc_score(y_test, yhat[:,-1])
print("AUC",train_accuracy)

from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier

clf =  GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=123, n_estimators=50)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
yhat = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

# AUC metric
train_accuracy = roc_auc_score(y_test, yhat[:,-1])
print("AUC",train_accuracy)


from torch import nn
from skorch import NeuralNetBinaryClassifier
import torch

model = nn.Sequential(
          nn.Linear(8,64),
          nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
          nn.GELU(),
          nn.Linear(64,32),
          nn.BatchNorm1d(32),
          nn.GELU(),
          nn.Linear(32,16),
          nn.BatchNorm1d(16),
          nn.GELU(),
          nn.Linear(16,1),
#           nn.Sigmoid()
        )
net = NeuralNetBinaryClassifier(
    model,
    max_epochs=100,
    lr=0.1,
    # Shuffle training data on each epoch
    optimizer=torch.optim.Adam,
    iterator_train__shuffle=True,
)
net.fit(X_train, y_train)
 

from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier

clf = XGBClassifier(silent=0, 
                    learning_rate=0.01,  
                    min_child_weight=1,
                    max_depth=6,
                    objective='binary:logistic',
                    n_estimators=500,
                    seed=1000)

clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
yhat = clf.predict_proba(X_test)

# AUC metric
train_accuracy = roc_auc_score(y_test, yhat[:,-1])
print("AUC",train_accuracy)
```

Here is an attachment of a screenshot of the data.
[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz7tq.png)

Comment: Probably it is better to perform Stratified Cross Validation, and check AUC score on that. From your AUC score on test data, it seems your model is overfitting. 
Also for neural network, you should perform `one-hot-encoding` rather than `LabelEncoding` as NNs needs data to be standarized
You should also try Logistic Regression on one-hot-encoded features. Note that: for all the linear classifiers, normalizing the features matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fundamental first step of Data Analytics. You need to do two things here:

- Data understanding - do the data fields in their current format make sense (data types, value range etc.)
- Data preparation - what should I do to update these data fields before passing them to our model? Also which inputs do you think will be useful for your model and which will provide little benefit? Are there outliers I need to consider/handle?

A good book if you're starting in the field of data analytics is [Fundamentals of Machine Learning for Predictive Data Analytics](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-machine-learning-predictive-data-analytics)  (I have no affiliation with this book).

Looking at your dataset there's a couple of things you could try to see how it influences your prediction results:

- Unless region order is actually ranked in importance/value I would change this to a one hot encoded feature, you can do this in [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). Otherwise you run the risk of your model thinking that regions with a higher number (say 10) are more important than regions with a lower value (say 1).
- You could attempt to normalise certain categories if they are much larger than some of your other data fields [Why Data Normalization is necessary for Machine Learning models](https://medium.com/@urvashilluniya/why-data-normalization-is-necessary-for-machine-learning-models-681b65a05029)

Consider looking at the Kaggle competition [House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/overview). It's doing a similar thing to what you're attempting to do, and it might have some pointers for how you should approach the problem in the Notebooks and Discussion tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Without deeply exploring all the data you are using it is hard to say for certain what is causing the drop in accuracy (or AUC) when moving from your training set to the testing set.  **It is unlikely to be caused by the mixed discrete/continuous data**.

The drop just suggests that your models are over-fitting to your training data (and therefore not transferring well).  This could be caused by too many learned parameters (given the amount of data you have)--more often a problem with neural networks than with some of the other methods you mentioned.  Or, the problem could be with the way the data was split into training/testing.  If the distribution of the data has a significant difference (that's maybe not obvious) then you wouldn't expect the testing performance to be as good.  If it were me, I'd look carefully at how the data was split into training/testing (assuming you have a reasonably large set of data).  You may try repeating your experiments with a number of random training/testing splits (search k-fold cross validation if you're not familiar with it).

Answer (score 0):

your model is overfit. try to make a simple model first and use a lower parameter value. for tree-based classification, scaling does not have any impact on the model.